# A store is selling 5 types of hard candies. How many ways are there to chose?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The choices are lemon, cherry, strawberry, orange, and pineapple.

How many ways are there to chose $35$ candies? I thought it would be $35^5$ because there are $35$ choices with $5$ options but that is not correct.

Next, how many ways can you get at least one of each flavor?

Then, how many ways can you get at least $2$ cherry and at least $4$ lemon?

Comment: Would (35^5)-1 be correct? This sounds like homework.

Comment: @Optionparty, not really. Where did you get that?

Comment: See the Wikipedia article on [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problems; it has a fairly decent explanation.

Comment: If you care about the order you choose, it would be $5^{35}$.  If you don't care about the order, but just the collection you have at the end, the stars and bars answers are what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You have 35 candies to choose. Let's say you have four "bars"; they separate the types of candies from each other. e.g.:

-------|-------|-------|-------|-------

Means 7 candies of each. The answer is 39C4 because this is only a rearrangement problem.

The second one, assume that each has one candies. Then it's just 30 candies to choose and 4 bars again.

Same for the last one; you choose 35-2-4=29 candies with 4 bars.

If you want to learn more, search "sticks and bars". It's a powerful method.

Comment: The name usually used here is [*stars and bars*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); the link is to the Wikipedia article, which has a decent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing $35$ candies with $5$ options, is the same as partitioning $35$ to a sum of $5$ integers (decide that every integer will be for a specific candy).
One way to do this, is looking at $35+4=39$ place holders, choosing $4$ of them as dividers and deciding that every area between placeholders represents the number of candies you take from a specific type is exactly the partition of $35$ candies to $5$ flavors.
That is, the solution to your first question is ${35+4}\choose{4}$.

The second and third follow the same logic, if you have at least one of each flavor, you have only $30$ left to choose, so the solution is ${30+4}\choose{4}$.

And finally, with $2$ cherry and $4$ lemon, there are $29$ left to choose from, so the solution is ${29+4}\choose{4}$.

Comment: Small error: with one of each flavor you have only $30$ left to choose.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer $1$**

You have $5$ types of candies, but this types are always available.

Now you want to choose $35$ candies, each time you have the possibility to choose from one of the $5$ types.

So we have $5^35$ ways, means $34359738368$ possibilities.

**Answer 2**

$${n\choose k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!  k!}$$

means

${35\choose 5} = 7791168$ different ways.

Comment: I’m afraid that none of these is correct; see the answers by user43400 and Daugmented for a correct approach.

Comment: thx, Mr. Scott!

Answer (score 0):

I know painfully little about higher math, but perhaps I can help you phrase the question another way.

You are talking about a domain of five: l, c, s, o, p. One can think of this a 35-digit number in base 4 (we ignore the blank, or zero, value). Given that we never have an empty slot, we could count

```
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppo
pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppps
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppc
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppl
pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppop
...
```

So the number of possible combinations is

```
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
```

Comment: I’m afraid that this approach doesn’t work; see the answers by user43400 and Daugmented for a correct approach.